# Java Resolve IPv6 incorrect

Tags: java, dns, network-programming, ipv6

I'm trying to resolve IPv6 address using Java code I wrote which returns the host name the same as the given, while running `nslookup` it resolve a real name:

[image: nslookup snapshot]
.

Here is the Java code:

```
try
{
    Inet6Address addr = (Inet6Address) Inet6Address.getByName("2607:f8b0:4002:c06::65");
    System.out.println("Host: " + addr.getHostName());
}
catch (UnknownHostException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
Host: 2607:f8b0:4002:c06:0:0:0:65
```

Why is that? does Java have a different DNS resolver?

Comment: Those are the same addresses. 2607:f8b0:4002:c06:0:0:0:65 is the same as 2607:f8b0:4002:c06::65. RFC 5952 clarifies the original IPv6 address format, and, clearly, your Java is not conforming to that RFC, but that does not mean it is a different or incorrect address.

Comment: Java is a compiled language, not a scripting language.

Comment: nslookup has a different DNS resolver: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup

Also on my machine your program returns `Host: yv-in-x65.1e100.net`. Try adding the Google DNS (8.8.8.8) maybe

Comment: CaptainCap Thanks, I ended up using http://www.dnsjava.org where i could set the DNS server.